# Exceute Remote Server power-shell script using Apache camel

Tags: apache, shell, ssh, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to know is there any component or way in "Apache Camel" to execute a remote power shell-script by passing some argument.

My requirement are, i need to get message from a queue and route it by calling a remote power shell-script with some argument

I already checked camel

```
   ssh component   
   ftp2 component   
and
   exec component
```

But I don't get any solution from above component.

thanks

Comment: The exec component should probably handle this. What have you tried and what is your issue?

Comment: we can use "exec" for shell execution but how can i access that remote server to execute that script?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a local power shell script that will execute the remote script. Then call the local script from camel.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx